# insert/remove HTML content between div tags

Tags: javascript, dom

how can I insert some HTML code between `<div id="mydiv">...</div>` using javascript?

Ex: `<div id="mydiv"><span class="prego">Something</span></div>` its about 10 lines of html of most. thank you

Comment: Are you replacing the HTML in the div, or inserting more into the div?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you're replacing the contents of the div and have the HTML as a string you can use the following:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = '<span class="prego">Something</span>';
```

Answer (score 21):

A simple way to do this with vanilla JavaScript would be to use `appendChild`.

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var mycontent = document.createElement("p");
mycontent.appendChild(document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph"));
mydiv.appendChild(mycontent);
```

Or you can use `innerHTML` as others have mentioned.

Or if you would like to use jQuery, the above example could be written as:

```
$("#mydiv").append("<p>This is a paragraph</p>");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
// Build it using this variable
var content = "<span class='prego'>....content....</span>"; 
// Insert using this:
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = content;
```

Answer (score 5):

That's really kind of an ambiguous request. There are many ways this can be accomplished.

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = '<span class="prego">Something</span>';
```

That is the *simplest*. OR;

```
var spn = document.createElement('span');
spn.innerHTML = 'Something';
spn.className = 'prego';
document.getElementById('mydiv').appendChild(spn);
```

Preferred to both of these methods would be to use a Javascript library that creates shortcut methods for the simple things like this, such as mootools. (http://mootools.net)

With mootools this task would look like:

```
new Element('span', {'html': 'Something','class':'prego'}).inject($('mydiv'));
```

Comment: In this case using mootools isn't much of a shortcut. You save only six characters, and have to understand a new framework. Mootools might be appropriate for more complex functionality, especially where the solution differs per browser.

Answer (score 3):

```
 document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "<span class='prego'>Something</span>";
```

Should do it. If you are willing to use jQuery it could be easier.

Answer (score 3):

document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = 'whatever';

Answer (score 3):

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = '<span class="prego">Something</span>';
```

jQuery

```
$("#mydiv").append('<span class="prego">Something</span>');
```