# regex replace characters with html tag in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm getting with regex words I need to replace with input tag. But when I'm adding html , it reads as plain string.
Here is my string: "Hello, my name is /# Ann #/. I'm working for /# IStaff #/, could you please call me back". Where i'm doing mistake?

```
editModalText() {
  const { modalMessage } = this.state
  let regex = /\/#(.*?)#\//g
  let replaced = modalMessage.replace(regex, '<input type="text">')
  return replaced
}

<div>{this.editModalText()}</div>
```

Comment: Is your issue the greedy dot? Try `/#(.*?)#/g` What is the expected result?

Comment: paste your page code

Answer (score 1):

This is because it **is** a plain string.

You're going to have to change your approach entirely if you want to mix JSX syntax into your template.

For example, build a [tokenizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization) that would convert your string into an array like:

```
[
    "Hello, my name is ",
    "/# Ann #/",
    ". I'm working for ",
    "/# IStaff #/",
    ", could you please call me back"
]
```

Then loop over it and push either the raw string or an appropriate JSX element into a new array, and finally return that.

Answer (score 0):

You can match the middle part by using `.*?`.

```js
let modalMessage = "Hello, my name is /# Ann #/. I'm working for /# IStaff #/, could you please call me back";
let regex = /\/#(.*?)#\//g;
let replaced = modalMessage.replace(regex, "<input />");
console.log(replaced);
```

Also you need to escape your `/` in the regex with a backslash (\). 
A valid expression starts and ends with `/`:

`/<regex>/<flags>`

So in your example:

```
/          // <- Start of Regular expression
  \/       // <- Match /
  #        // <- Match #
    (.*?)  // <- Match the middle part (non-greedy)
  #        // <- Match #
  \/       // <- Match /
/g         // <- End regex and set "global" flag
```

---

Example with HTML:

```js
let modalMessage = "Hello, my name is /# Ann #/. I'm working for /# IStaff #/, could you please call me back";
let regex = /\/#(.*?)#\//g;
let replaced = modalMessage.replace(regex, '<input type="text">');

document.write(replaced);
```

Comment: it displays "Hello, my name is <Input />. I'm working for <Input />, could you please call me back." I need actual input , where user can type

Comment: is it possible insert input without document.write(replaced)?

Comment: Of course. You can insert it where you want. You didn't provide any HTML, just the string in JavaScript. So I don't know where you ant it. But you could for example [put it inside a Div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1750428/7575111).

Comment: innerHtml doesn't work for me.My dom renders after that function runs. Could you pls suggest any other way?

Comment: @YerlanYeszhanov Then wait for your DOM to be loaded. Put the script in the <head> of your page and use the `DOMContentLoaded` event: https://jsfiddle.net/9mbaLx8q/

Comment: Instead of using a lazy quantifier, used a negated character class with a greedy quantifier.

Answer (score -1):

You aren't catching the / around the placeholders (/ being a regex special character that needs to be escaped)

using `(.+)` or `(.*)` will provide a *greedy* match. It means, it will match as much as possible, that's why you are matching too much. You want to use a lazy match (the opposite of greedy, that stops as soon as possible), `(.+?)` or `(.*?)`

You can use this one :

```js
let modalMessage = "Hello, my name is /# Ann #/. I'm working for /# IStaff #/, could you please call me back"
let regex = /\/#(.*?)#\//g
let replaced = modalMessage.replace(regex, '<Input />')
console.log(replaced)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you keep the `+` quantifier ? `/\/#(.+?)#\//g`

Comment: He can, this is to make sure `/##/` is also taken in account

Comment: it displays "Hello, my name is <Input />. I'm working for <Input />, could you please call me back." I need actual input , where user can type

Comment: You can't have it in a `console.log()`. You might want to insert it as HTML.

Comment: That is now another question. You've edited your question and fixed it