# Add to cart Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cart

So I need to add something to my cart `#cart` in the id `#items`. The problem is that I dont know how to add a section from html to another.

Comment: Not that it means much, but the html in this question is suspiciously similar to the html in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59088177/refer-to-a-tag-in-javascript/59088438#59088438). Is this for a programming course or what?

Comment: Where's you javascript code? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [insert/remove HTML content between div tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750416/insert-remove-html-content-between-div-tags)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code.

```js
document.querySelector('#card .items').appendChild(document.querySelector('[data-id="22"]').cloneNode(true));
```

Comment: and what if it depends on which product is selected? like if there are 22 diffrent ID's

Comment: Simply pass the different productId.

Comment: but it depends on what they choose

Comment: @gip please amend your question to ask *exactly* what you need, what you tried and how it's not working, not some vague "add something to html", because there's plenty of answers about that already (including the one I linked above).